# NameError: updateDataSource

Tags: python, weblogic, datasource, soa, wlst

I am getting the NameError: while running the below from a .py script
Anyone know what should be the 5th parameter if I want to update the datasource on the AdminServer.

updateDataSource(WLS, DRIVERNAME, URL, 'STB', '', DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX, DB_SCHEMA_PASSWORD)

Comment: Please post your script, my assumption is updateDataSource isn't defined or imported anywhere. You get the error because Python can't find that name anywhere in scope.

Comment: I added the import as follows                                                                  from configure_datasource import upgrade_datasources                          but am getting import failure error. The file configure_datasource.py is available in the same folder. What am I missing now. Any help?